# Python: My plot is not showing any Circles, any clues?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The plot is only showing a white screen and I am not entirely sure why. I would like the planets to orbit around the sun at different positions, in that, I used the FuncAnimation to make it happen.

```
from pylab import* 
from matplotlib.animation import *

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-10, 10), ylim=(-10, 10), aspect=True)
x0 =0 
y0 = 0
r_s=.15
r_e = .15
r_m = .15
Sun, = plt.Circle((x0, y0), radius=r_s, ec='yellow', fc='yellow', lw=3)
Earth, = plt.Circle((2, 4), radius=r_e, ec='green', fc='green', lw=3)
Mars, = plt.Circle((1, 3), radius=r_M, ec='brown', fc='brown', lw=3)
ax.add_patch(Sun)

def init():

    ax.add_patch(Earth)
    ax.add_patch(Mars)
    return  Earth, Mars,

def animate(i):

    theta = radians(i)
    x = x0*np.cos(theta) - y0*np.sin(theta)
    y = x0*np.sin(theta) + y0*np.cos(theta)
    Earth.xy = (-x, -y)
    Earth._angle = i
    Mars.xy = (x, y)
    Mars._angle = i
    return Earth, Mars,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=1080, 
                               interval=25, blit=True)


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was playing around with your code. The main problem is that the result of (x,y) is always (0,0) since your value multiplying `sin` and `cos` is `x0` with is zero. In any case, this is the version that worked for me:

```
from matplotlib.animation import *

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-10, 10), ylim=(-10, 10), aspect=True)
x0 =0 
y0 = 0
r_s=.15
r_e = .15
r_m = .15
d_e = 1
d_m = 2
Sun = plt.Circle((x0, y0), radius=r_s, ec='yellow', fc='yellow', lw=3)
Earth = plt.Circle((2, 4), radius=r_e, ec='green', fc='green', lw=3)
Mars = plt.Circle((1, 3), radius=r_m, ec='brown', fc='brown', lw=3)
ax.add_patch(Sun)

def init():
    ax.add_patch(Earth)
    ax.add_patch(Mars)
    return  Earth, Mars,

def animate(i):

    theta = radians(i)
    ex = d_e*np.cos(theta) - d_e*np.sin(theta)
    ey = d_e*np.sin(theta) + d_e*np.cos(theta)
    mx = d_m*np.cos(theta) - d_m*np.sin(theta)
    my = d_m*np.sin(theta) + d_m*np.cos(theta)
    Earth.center = (ex, ey)
    Earth._angle = i
    Mars.center = (mx, my)
    Mars._angle = i
    return Earth, Mars,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=1080, 
                               interval=25, blit=True)


plt.show()
```